# Retrieve match string data in QueryBuilder

Tags: symfony, query-builder

Query :

```
$gigTypeEntity = $query->select('u.id,u.fullName,u.usertype')
                       ->from('UserBundle:User', 'u')
                       //->where('u.usertype='.$usertype)
                       ->groupBy('u.id')
                       ->getQuery()
                       ->getResult();
```

Response Like this:-

```
array(
    [id] => 1
    [fullName] => Tom
    [usertype] => Duo, Band
)
```

I want to check usertype(string) value which is match with $usertype.

for Example :-

> $usertype = 'Duo';

so, how can I Retrive data of match with $usertype ??

Comment: Try with `LIKE` clause: `->where('u.usertype LIKE \'%:type%\'')->setParameter('type', $usertype)`

Comment: @rokas post this comment as an answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

If I am right, you want to execute `where u.usertype = $userType` query.

You can do something like:

```
$gigTypeEntity = $query->select('u.id,u.fullName,u.usertype')
                       ->from('UserBundle:User', 'u')
                       ->where('u.usertype=:usertype')
                       ->groupBy('u.id')
                       ->setParameter('usertype', $usertype);
                       ->getQuery()
                       ->getResult();
```

Please correct me if assumption is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `LIKE` clause:

```
$gigTypeEntity = $query->select('u.id,u.fullName,u.usertype')
                       ->from('UserBundle:User', 'u')
                       ->where('u.usertype LIKE \'%:type%\'')
                       ->setParameter('type', $usertype)
                       ->groupBy('u.id')
                       ->getQuery()
                       ->getResult();
```